# Excel VBA How to pass range from different sheet to function properly?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to work with range of cells from different sheet in Excel VBA.
Here is my code:

```
Function LastDayForClient(client As String, mnth As Integer, dates As range) As String

Dim dtRow As Date
Dim dt As range

dtRow = 0

For Each dt In dates
      ' If not that month that we are looking for - go next
     If month(dt.Value) = mnth Then
       ' If not that client - go next
        If Cells(dt.Row, dt.Column + 1).Value = client Then

          If dtRow = 0 Then
            dtRow = dt.Value
          ElseIf dtRow < dt.Value Then
            dtRow = dt.Value
          End If
        End If
      End If
Next dt

LastDayForClient = Format(dtRow, "dd.mm.yyyy")

End Function
```

That's how I want to use the formula:

```
=LastDayForClient("Client_name";5;Diff_sheet!G6:G297)
```

I guess that I'm using passed `Range` argument somehow in a wrong way, as I'm getting wrong value when using formula on different sheet. When the range is on the same sheet everything is fine.

Comment: why the use of Format, wouldn't `month(dt.Value2)` work without the need of the extra step?

Comment: Thanks for your remark @ScottCraner! Not sure why I used it that way..
Anyways, what is about the Range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the line

```
If Cells(dt.Row, dt.Column + 1).Value = client Then
```

Cells refers to the ActiveSheet, so you need to tell Cells to refer to the right sheet.

```
Dim wks as worksheet
set wks = dates.parent
```

and then

```
If wks.Cells(dt.Row, dt.Column + 1).Value = client Then
```

Comment: Thank you @Storax for your quick answer! Works brilliant!